# How to add values inside the variable into array

Tags: php

```
$elements = array();
                                               
while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($allquestionRes)) {
    $elements[] = $getrow['q']; 
}

$my_elements = implode(',',$elements); // For example Displays 658,659
$my_array = array($my_elements);
$to_remove = explode(',', $my_elements);
$result = array_diff($my_array,$to_remove);
$random = $result[array_rand($result)];

echo $random; // Output 658 or 659
```

I want to add the implode values and put them inside the array and then display the random result as given in the lines of code.

Comment: can you explain it more with the output that you expect??

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
$elements = array();

while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($allquestionRes)) {
   $elements[] = $getrow['q']; // For example records 657,658,659...
}

$i = rand(0, (count($elements)-1));

$random = $elements[$i];

echo $random; // Output 657 or 658 or 659
```

This should solve the problem base on your explanation.

Comment: What I want to display the random result using implode string to put into the array

Comment: @RazaBarlasMills you can just do a random selection, I will edit my solution for you again.

Comment: @RazaBarlasMills Check my solution again. It should solve the problem

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: I just want to put $my_elements = implode(',',$elements); inside the array. To display the automatically values and then it differentiate both arrays

$result = array_diff($my_array,$to_remove);


$random = $result[array_rand($result)];

Comment: Are you trying to do a mathematical operation?

Comment: Yes. I want to put the values of $my_elements = implode(',',$elements); inside the array. The one which is $my_array

Comment: I'm lost on what you are trying to do, you are not giving clear explanation

Comment: I am saying I want to put the implode values inside the array that is $my_array and then I wanted to show the random values.

Comment: How do I put the implode values inside the array $my_array so I can display them the random values